# php preg_replace replacing hashtags

Tags: php

I'm using this code to make hashtags:

```
preg_replace(  '/\#([A-Za-z0-9]*)/is', ' <a href="tag/$1"> #$1</a> ', $text);
```

It works, but when it comes across this: "it#039;s" (  "it's" ), it replaces it as well.
So I guess I want it to only replace hashtags if they have a white space before them, or are at the beginning of the line. Something like in this string below:

> This is a #tag and this is
>    #anotherTag but the word "it's" and "it#039;s" is not being replaced

How do I change the preg to do this?
Thanks

Comment: And if the word starts with a special character? Aren't you better off searching for any non-whitespace sequence that starts with # and ends with ; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is a **negative lookbehind**

```
/(?<!=|\b|&)#([a-z0-9_]+)/i
```

Notice the `?<!=` part, this is saying match the hashtags where there isn't a `\b` or `#` in front of it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I changed it to this, and it worked: /(\s|\n)#([a-z0-9_]+)/is

Comment: @SumitKumar That's not ideal because it won't match hashtags at the start of the string, for example `$text = '#hello and #hello';`